# how to unzip a attachment in outlook and save it to a foldeer using vba

Tags: vba, outlook

currently i have an Email that comes in and my vba code will save the file to a folder, however since this code was made they now send me the file in a zip file.  This of course breaks the code and i have to resend it in a non zip file to make it work.  Here is a sample of what I am currently using:

If Left(objItem.Subject, 28) = "xxxxx report Toolbox" Then

```
    For Each Atmt In objItem.Attachments
            FileName = "O:\Automated Reports\toolbox.xlsx"
            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
            modify_file
        Debug.Print "success CSAT file"
        Open "O:\Automated Reports\toolboxDate.JW" For Output As #1
        Write #1, Right(objItem.Subject, 5)
        Close #1
    Next Atmt

End If
```

As i stated before this code woks fine for just saving the file when it is not a .zip file.  I need it to unzip the file and save it to the O: drive.  I have tried to use some shell.application objects but i didn't quite get that to work.  Thanks for any help ahead of time

Answer (score 0):

```
'Create new blank zip.
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Ag(0), 8, vbtrue)
BlankZip = "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6)
For x = 0 to 17
    BlankZip = BlankZip & Chr(0)
Next
ts.Write BlankZip

'Unzip
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set SrcFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(1))
Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(0))
Set FldrItems=SrcFldr.Items
DestFldr.CopyHere FldrItems, &H214
Msgbox "Finished"

'Zip
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(1))
Set SrcFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(0))
Set FldrItems=SrcFldr.Items
DestFldr.CopyHere FldrItems, &H214
Msgbox "Finished"
```

Comment: When i try and use the Unzip portion of this code the Ag=wscript.arguments errors out.  Not really sure what it does either.  When i looked it up it is a connection to windows? The &H214 do i need to replace that with the rootfile i want it to go to?  Apologize the error is a rt 424 error.

Comment: They are command line arguments. `zip source destination`. You may notice the only difference between zip and unzip is source and destination is reversed.